# Recurrence relations and asymptotic complexity

Tags: math, recurrence, asymptotic-complexity

I am trying to understand the recurrence relation of `f(n) = n^cos n` and `g(n) = n`. I am told that this relation has no asymptotic behavior related to Big O, little o, Big Omega, little omega, or Theta. Something about the oscillations of cos n? Can I receive a little more understanding on this behavior? 
 
When I use L' Hospital rule on my calculator, I get `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

The function n<sup>cos n</sup> is O(n). Since -1 ≤ cos n ≤ 1, the function n<sup>cos n</sup> is always bounded between n<sup>-1</sup> and n<sup>1</sup>, so in particular it's always upper-bounded by O(n). However, it's not Ω(n), because for any number n<sub>0</sub> and any constant c, you can find an n > n<sub>0</sub> where n<sup>cos n</sup> < cn. One way to do this is to look for choices of n where cos n is negative; the value of n<sup>-ε</sup> for any ε > 0 will eventually be smaller than cn for any c.

Hope this helps!